# Reset jquery function and clear variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic site where clicking an element spawns a new element(`div`) and assigns both elements matching `data-id` attributes. I want to tinker with the new `div`, so I have a little script that finds the new `div` from the matching `data-id`.

That all works great:

```
var id = 123; //this represents the randomly generated data-id

$('.modules').click(function() {
    var addOne = $(this);

   //**this is just to simulate what the live site does: appending the clicked element with 'data-id="[the random id]"**
    $(addOne).attr('data-id', id);

    //put the data-id value from the click element in a variable
    var addedId = addOne.data('id'); 

    //find the newly created DOM element with the matching data-id value and make it a variable
    var module = $('.module-added[data-id="' + addedId + '"]')[0]; 

    //check and make sure I got the element so I can mess with it.
    var x = module.getAttribute("data-id"); 
    alert(x);
   // element.scrollIntoView(); //like maybe this
});
```

However, the new `div` can be deleted and the `data-id` drops off the click element, then the click element can be clicked again spawning a *new* `div` - both having fresh `data-id`s.

My problem comes when the click element is re-clicked. My script is still holding on to the original `data-id` value, not picking up the newly assigned one.

I'm pretty sure this is really simple, but I'm such a newbie.

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nericksx/pen/qxrmpw?editors=1010) for reference

Comment: jquery `off` method?

Comment: Try changing `var addedId = addOne.data('id');` to `var addedId = addOne.attr('data-id');`.

Comment: @John S - I thought data('id') and attr('data-id') were functionally the same... but apparently they are not. That did the trick. Thank you!